# How to cd to where I extracted a package, and run dpkg-deb -D?

Tags: dpkg, thinkpad, deb, command-line

I am following the step-by-step instructions on how to install ThinkPad Fan Control [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10112573&postcount=3) but I could not get past this step (seen below):

> Open a terminal and run this command:
>
> Code:
>
> `dpkg-deb -D --build tpfan admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all`

instead I get this message when I enter it in the terminal:

> dpkg-deb: error: failed to open package info file
>   `tpfan/DEBIAN/control' for reading: No such file or directory

The .deb file is in my Downloads folder so I tried `cd ./Downloads dpkg-deb -D --build tpfan admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all`  but I get `juno@Oogushi:~/Downloads$`.

How can I run the command properly? I'm not familiar with the terminal and commands so I don't know how to do this properly.

I am using ThinkPad R61i 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd ./Downloads` and `dpkg-deb -D --build tpfan admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all` are two separate commands. You must run them separately.

So, after `cd`ing to the `Downloads` folder, just run this command as before:

```
dpkg-deb -D --build tpfan admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all
```

It appears that the only problem was that you were in the wrong place when you ran it. Or, more accurately, that you specified a relative path (see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)), which was wrong *relative to the current working directory*. By changing the current working directory, the relative path `tpfan` *should* be correct, assuming `tpfan` exists in your `Downloads` folder.

Edit: **Whatever directory *contains* the `tpfan` directory, that's where you should be (i.e., where you should `cd` to) when you run your `dpkg-deb` command.**

Comment: I did the two commands separately, however I still get                   
`juno@Oogushi:~/Downloads$ dpkg-deb -D --build tpfan admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all
dpkg-deb: error: failed to open package info file `tpfan/DEBIAN/control' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: @onvas Have you verified that the `tpfan` directory exists inside `Downloads`?

Comment: I copied the files to another folder I named `tpfan` and repeated the command: `juno@Oogushi:~$ cd ./Downloads
juno@Oogushi:~/Downloads$ dpkg-deb -D --build tpfan admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all
dpkg-deb: warning: 'tpfan/DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field 'Python-Version'
dpkg-deb: warning: ignoring 1 warning about the control file(s)

dpkg-deb: building package `tpfan-admin' in `admin_0.96-ubuntu1_all'.
juno@Oogushi:~/Downloads$`

Comment: @onvas From those messages, it looks like the new `.deb` file was successfully built. Do you have it? (It should be in `Downloads` as well.)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry the new .deb file just appeared now. Thank you very much for your help.